# Compare two objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have constructed objects as follow:

Object 1

```
[ { 
   ext: '1287',
   ip: '(Unspecified)',
   queue: [ ]
 } ]
```

Object 2

```
 [ { Queue: '222',
    Members:
     [ {"ext":"1287"},
       {"ext":"4118"} ],
    Callers: [] },

  { Queue: '111',
    Members:
     [ {"ext":"4131"},
       {"ext":"1287"},
       {"ext":"4138"}
     ],
    Callers: [] }]
```

I want to compare Object 1 and Object 2. If the value of ext key from Object 1 exists in the nested Members object of Object 2 then
the value of Queue should be pushed to a queue array and the final object should be like as shown below.

Final Object that I want

```
   [{ ext: '1287',
   ip: '(Unspecified)',
   queue: [222, 111 ] }]
```

I need some hints regarding how a nested object like this is compared using lodash.

Comment: `'{"ext":"4131"}'` is a string in the question. Is it a typo?

Comment: a) There is no such thing as *JSON objects*. b) You show arrays, not objects. c) Your JSON is invalid, property names b must be quoted in JSON.

Comment: '{"ext":"4131"}',
       '{"ext":"1287"}',
       '{"ext":"4138"}'
object 2 is members are array of string OR  each behaving as an individual object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution without mutations:

```js
const obj1 = [{ext: '1287',ip: '(Unspecified)',queue: []}];
const obj2 = [{Queue: '222',Members: [{"ext":"1287"},{"ext":"4118"}],Callers: []},{Queue: '111',Members: [{"ext":"4131"},{"ext":"1287"},{"ext":"4138"}],Callers: []}];

const hasExt = ext => o2 => o2.Members.some(m => m.ext === ext)

const result = obj1.map(o1 => {
  const newQueue = obj2
    .filter(hasExt(o1.ext))
    .map(m => m.Queue);
    
  return { ...o1, queue: [...o1.queue, ...newQueue] };
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey this solution is also very helpful. Thank you

Comment: Hey how do I do it if I want the array like this [
  {
    "ext": "1287",
    "ip": "(Unspecified)",
    "queue": [
      {"number" : "222"},
      {"number" : "111"}
    ]
  }
]

Comment: @pravinnavle change `.map(m => m.Queue)` to `.map(m => ({number: m.Queue}))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Sorry I'm accepting more and more help.

Comment: One last help that I need, suppose in my obj2, in the objects of the Members array I have another key after ext as name like this :  obj2 = [{Queue: '222',Members: [{"ext":"1287","name" :"Alex"},{"ext":"4118","name" :"George"}],Callers: []}];  I want to push the name key and it's value from Members to the queue array of obj1. I want the queue array to look like  "queue": [ {"number" : "222","name": "Alex" } How to do it? Also suggest me a good resource to learn about => and ... thing

Comment: the name key value should be that of the matching object(i.e ext of Members from obj2 matches the ext of obj1). I tried it like this map(m => ({number: m.Queue, name: m.Members[0].name}));  and I'm getting some output but it's from the first object and hence not correct. But I want the name from the object whose ext matches in obj1 and obj2. Please help me with this

Comment: @pravinnavle `.map(m => ({number: m.Queue, name: m.Members.find(m => m.ext === o1.ext).name}))` best resource for web platform is https://developer.mozilla.org. If you want to go deep with js -> https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS. or videos at https://frontendmasters.com (all courses are free to watch this week)

Comment: sir, can you help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53700568/angularjs-custom-filter-to-check-for-values-inside-a-data-array)

Answer (score 3):

You can try following using [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
let obj1 = [{ext: '1287',ip: '(Unspecified)',queue: []}];
let obj2 = [{Queue: '222',Members: [{"ext":"1287"},{"ext":"4118"}],Callers: []},{Queue: '111',Members: [{"ext":"4131"},{"ext":"1287"},{"ext":"4138"}],Callers: []}];

obj1.forEach(o => {
  obj2.forEach(v => {
    let exists = v.Members.some(m => m.ext === o.ext);
    if (exists) o.queue.push(v.Queue);
  });
});

console.log(obj1);
```

**Improvement**

You can improve the performance by first creating a `map` of `obj1` with `ext` as `key` and `object` as `value`. Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
let obj1 = [{ext: '1287',ip: '(Unspecified)',queue: []}];
let obj2 = [{Queue: '222',Members: [{"ext":"1287"},{"ext":"4118"}],Callers: []},{Queue: '111',Members: [{"ext":"4131"},{"ext":"1287"},{"ext":"4138"}],Callers: []}];

let map = obj1.reduce((a, c) => Object.assign(a, {[c.ext] : c}), new Map());

obj2.forEach(v => {
  v.Members.forEach(m => {
    if(map[m.ext]) map[m.ext].queue.push(v.Queue);
  });
});

console.log(obj1);
```

Comment: Thanks, Nikhil. This solution is perfect. Also, I corrected my question

Comment: @NAVLEPRAVIN - Glad to help you!